# Get text elements from xml tag and tag's optional children with ElemTree Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a xml document (saved on my drive):

```
xml="""
<?xml version="1.0">
<front>
<z id="37">some text sitting here</z>
<label>&#26;</label>
<z id="38">Another sentence to read.</z>
<z id="39">The contents of a document.</z> 
<sec id="sec-introduction" sec-type="intro">
<z id="40">This document is called <std><std-id std-id-link-type="urn" std-id-type="undated">101...</std-id><std-ref>help me!</std-ref></std>, <italic>Stcks guide to xml text</italic>. </z></front>
"""
```

I want to extract all of the text elements to store in a dataframe that would resemble this:

| Id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 37 | some text sitting here |
| 38 | Another sentence to read |
| ... | ... |
| 40 | this document is called 101...help me! Stacks guide to xml text |

I have used this to produce a dataframe but it misses out the text that sits within the extra tags

```
file = ('[my_file_location.xml')
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

xmltext = []

for z in root.iter('z'):
    txt = z.text
    xmltext.append(txt)
```

I can obviously get the "some text sitting here" and "another sentence to read." elements, but i cannot pick up any text from elements within the p tags, i.e `std-a`, `std-b` etc

Comment: Have updated the post to include my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iterparse() with itertext() as mentioned from **@Daniel Haley**, plus pandas() if needed.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml = """<front>
<z id="37">some text sitting here</z>
<label>foo</label>
<z id="38">Another sentence to read.</z>
<z id="39">The contents of a document.</z> 
<sec id="sec-introduction" sec-type="intro">
<z id="40">This document is called <std><std-id std-id-link-type="urn" std-id-type="undated">101...</std-id><std-ref>help me!</std-ref></std>, <italic>Stcks guide to xml text</italic>. </z>
</sec>
</front>
"""
f = StringIO(xml)

data = []
columns = ['id', 'TEXT']

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(f, events=('start', 'end', 'comment', 'pi')):
    #print(event, elem.tag, elem.attrib, elem.text, elem.tail)
    if elem.get('id') is not None and event == 'end':
        if elem.get('id').isnumeric() and elem.text:
            # I gave @Daniel a vote
            txt = "".join(elem.itertext())
            print(elem.get('id'), txt)
            row = elem.get('id'), txt
            data.append(row)
            

print()           
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
37 some text sitting here
38 Another sentence to read.
39 The contents of a document.
40 This document is called 101...help me!, Stcks guide to xml text. 

id                                                              TEXT
37                                            some text sitting here
38                                         Another sentence to read.
39                                       The contents of a document.
40 This document is called 101...help me!, Stcks guide to xml text.
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do in this case would be to use `itertext()` to get the text.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pprint import pprint

xml = """<front>
<z id="37">some text sitting here</z>
<label>foo</label>
<z id="38">Another sentence to read.</z>
<z id="39">The contents of a document.</z> 
<sec id="sec-introduction" sec-type="intro">
<z id="40">This document is called <std><std-id std-id-link-type="urn" std-id-type="undated">101...</std-id><std-ref>help me!</std-ref></std>, <italic>Stcks guide to xml text</italic>. </z>
</sec>
</front>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

xmltext = []

for z in root.iter('z'):
    txt = "".join(z.itertext())
    xmltext.append(txt)

pprint(xmltext)
```

Printed output...

```py
['some text sitting here',
 'Another sentence to read.',
 'The contents of a document.',
 'This document is called 101...help me!, Stcks guide to xml text. ']
```